# jQuery - Change background of input field if text getting replaced

Tags: jquery, textbox, replace, background-color

I'm currently using jQuery to restrict a text box to number only input as follows:

```
    $('input.numbersOnly').keyup(function () { 
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
    });
```

I'd like to let the user know that what they are typing is being rejected by changing the background color of the field. I know that I can change the background of a field using something like this:

```
     $('input.numbersOnly').addClass('alertClass');
```

My question is, how do I combine the two code examples above so that the color of the field changes as the character is getting replaced? My goal is to alert the user that something is wrong with their input as they type it in the field.

Thanks!

Comment: when should the alertClass be removed?

Comment: What happens when the user types "1234a" (which is reduced to "1234") and then tabs onto next field?

Comment: Nickf - Hadn't thought much about that, but Nick Craver's solution below is elegant enough that I like it, so I'm moving forward with his suggestion.

Salman A - I set it such that alertClass is removed when the user tabs to the next field. I used the following:

  $('input').focusout(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass('alertClass', false);
  });

It works well for what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('input.numbersOnly').keyup(function () { 
    var newValue = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
    if(this.value !== newValue) $(this).addClass('alertClass');
    this.value = newValue;
});
```

This grabs the new value, determines if you're actually replacing something, and if so adds the `alertClass`.  If you wanted to also remove the class on a valid `keyup` value, you could use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), like this:

```
$('input.numbersOnly').keyup(function () { 
    var newValue = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
    $(this).toggleClass('alertClass', this.value !== newValue);
    this.value = newValue;
});
```

This would toggle the class on with an invalid keyup, causing a value adjustment, and togle it off if the last keypress was a valid one, resulting in no adjustment.

Comment: Thank you Nick. This is exactly what I needed and you explained it well enough and linked the function documentation. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$('input.numbersOnly').keyup(function () { 
    var oldVal = this.value;
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
    if (oldVal !== this.value)
        $(this).addClass('alertClass')
});
```

Comment: Thank you for a response. This code would have worked as well.